# Strip leading zero from numeric vector without changing class

Tags: r

I have the following data, which is a few Major League Baseball statistics.

```
  Year   AVG   SLG  TB   OBP IsoPow    RC
1 1986 0.223 0.300 172 0.330  0.194  64.1
2 1987 0.261 0.356 271 0.329  0.230  92.8
3 1988 0.283 0.357 264 0.368  0.208 100.0
4 1989 0.248 0.328 247 0.351  0.178  91.9
5 1990 0.301 0.374 293 0.406  0.264 128.0
6 1991 0.292 0.367 262 0.410  0.222 118.2
```

Usually, percentage-type MLB statistics are displayed as a decimal, but with the leading zero removed.  I'd like to do the same, but also preserve the `class` of the variable, which in this case is `numeric`.

For example, with `bonds$AVG` I'd like the result to be a numeric vector that looks exactly like

```
[1] .223 .261 .283 .248 .301 .292
```

Using `sub`, the vector goes from numeric to character, then back to its original numeric state after wrapping it with `as.numeric`.

```
> sub(0, "", bonds$AVG)
# [1] ".223" ".261" ".283" ".248" ".301" ".292"
> as.numeric(sub(0, "", bonds$AVG))
# [1] 0.223 0.261 0.283 0.248 0.301 0.292
```

Is this possible in R?

```
bonds <-
structure(list(Year = c(1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991), 
    AVG = c(0.223, 0.261, 0.283, 0.248, 0.301, 0.292), SLG = c(0.3, 
    0.356, 0.357, 0.328, 0.374, 0.367), TB = c(172, 271, 264, 
    247, 293, 262), OBP = c(0.33, 0.329, 0.368, 0.351, 0.406, 
    0.41), IsoPow = c(0.194, 0.23, 0.208, 0.178, 0.264, 0.222
    ), RC = c(64.1, 92.8, 100, 91.9, 128, 118.2)), .Names = c("Year", 
"AVG", "SLG", "TB", "OBP", "IsoPow", "RC"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say it isn't possible. You could define a particular `print` method for your decimal values which leaves the `0` off, but I don't think there is a way to store values without it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was hoping for some wizardry. :)

Comment: Maybe something that, while the data sits in the data frame looks as I want it to, but when you take the values out, they have the zeros again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could generalize the following by modifying `print.data.frame`?

```
f1 <- function(x) noquote(sub(0, "", x))
f1(bonds$AVG)
.223 .261 .283 .248 .301 .292
```